# How to configure Canvas Payments for a Test App in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-canvas, facebook-payments

I'm trying to test an existing Facebook application. Previously the process was to create a 2nd application that you pointed your test server at (and vice versa). According to Facebooks app development documentation [Please find the link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps) a "**test app**" within the primary application is the way to go.

When I then go to configure payments in the "**test app**" it wants real company data and requires a valid tax id that has not been used in Facebook before. Obviously this is not going to work well. I have not found any documentation on configuring Canvas Payments for a "**test app**".

So, what is the correct way to configure Canvas Payments for a "test app"?